# How to make a field of multiple urls on a form

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14

How can I make a field of multiple links on a form. The url widget only allows for a single link to be put in.

I've tried making a text field (`fields.Text()`) and applying the url widget on my xml, but this basically changes the field to a single-lined one. Plus I've tried separating links with characters such as a whitespace, semi-colon, comma etc. for single-lined fields. Odoo reads the whole line as a link... including the delimiter.

Comment: What about a html field?

Comment: That wouldn't work I guess. The idea is to enter a links (possibly separated with a comma/newline) in a custom field called "Relevant Link(s)" . Then once the form is saved, the links should be clickable.

Comment: You could use 2 fields then. Where the html will be computed out of a Char field with comma-separated urls. In form views it is possible to show or hide fields if a user is or is not in edit mode. For example just use `class="oe_edit_only"` on a field if you want to show it in edit mode only.

Comment: Hmm how would this work. So when the user is entering the link, they'd be seeing the 2 fields? And when they click save, they'd only see the computed field?...

Comment: Yes this would work. You could also hide the computed field when in edit mode, if needed.

Comment: Yeah computed field would use the "oe_read_only" class. The real problem is the logic required to render the links entered in the comma separated char field to the computed html field.